# Get `children` prop from component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

UPDATE:

For anyone learning and confused on this as I was, this page describes what's going on -- my confusion was between a React *component* vs React *elements*
https://reactjs.org/docs/rendering-elements.html

ORIGINAL QUESTION:

The page linked below suggests the `children` prop is passed by default when using `FunctionComponent`, however it doesn't seem to work for me.  Given the following case, `props.children` is undefined.  I'm still picking up React -- what am I doing wrong?

```
import React, { FunctionComponent } from "react"

type Props = {
  myProp: string
}

const Nav: FunctionComponent<Props> = (props) => {
    console.log(props.myProp, props.children)
    return (
    <main>
        <nav>
        <a href="foo">FOO</a>
        <a href="bar" className="active">BAR</a>
      </nav>
    </main>
  )
}

// This component is rendered from within another component, e.g. `return (<div><Nav /></div>)
```

My end goal is to access a child attribute somehow.  The `active` class, for example.

source: https://fettblog.eu/typescript-react/children/

Comment: That's not a Functional Component you're returning. That's a string.

Comment: Also you seem to be directly calling that function, indeed without a children prop, not letting React render it.

Comment: In the actual app it is not a string, but I couldn't get it to work in JS Fiddle without the string.  Noted and edited.

Comment: The app renders this component from within another component, e.g. `return (<div><Nav /> </div>`. I'll remove the innerHTML to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`props.children === undefined` because you're rendering

```
<div>
  <Nav />
</div>
```

and `<Nav />` has no child element in it.

If you change it to something like

```
<Nav myProp="Hello">
  World!
</Nav>
```

then `console.log(props.myProp, props.children)` will print "Hello World!" in the console.

Comment: I see -- the `children` prop has nothing to do with the `Nav` component's return/render...  Thank you for the explanation!